# Converting Milliseconds into Clocktime Format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I've been trying to convert a milliseconds (0, 5000, 10000) column into a new column with the format: 00:00:00 (00:00:05, 00:00:10 etc)

I tried `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(5000/1000.0)` but it didn't give me the format I wanted.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The best is probably to convert to TimeDelta (using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)).

Thus you'll benefit from the timedelta object properties

```
s = pd.Series([0, 5000, 10000])
s2 = pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='ms')
```

output:

```
0   0 days 00:00:00
1   0 days 00:00:05
2   0 days 00:00:10
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you really want the '00:00:00' format, use instead [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
s2 = pd.to_datetime(s, unit='ms').dt.time
```

output:

```
0    00:00:00
1    00:00:05
2    00:00:10
dtype: object
```

optionally with `.astype(str)` to have strings

Answer (score 1):

Convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'], unit='ms')
print (df)
                  col
0 0 days 00:00:00
1 0 days 00:00:05
2 0 days 00:00:10
```